# Reading JSON without escape characters in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I want to read a  JSON file and get its content in the String variable. But, I'm getting escape characters like "\n" in it. How to read a JSON without these characters?

Input: any formatted JSON file

What I've tried:

1. Reading file content using Files.readAllBytes`. But, this gives escape characters.[image]

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(<file_path>));
```

2. Using JsonReader, it's giving error "**JsonReader at line 1 column 1 path $**"

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(Files.newBufferedReader(<file_path>));
String content = gson.fromJson(reader, String.class);
```

Solution

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(<file_path>));
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content);
String formattedString = obj.toString();
```

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java, i think you can found your answer here

Comment: Converting the original String to JSONObject and than again converting back to String gives a clean String. Marking the question as duplicate.